# mapping from $2^A$ to $P(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $2^A$ denote the set of all functions from set $A$ into two-element set 2.

> How to show that there exists one-to-one and onto mapping from $2^A$ to $P(A)$ (power set)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

- For a function $f : A \to 2$ and an element $a \in A$, either $f(a) = 0$ or $f(a) = 1$.
- For a subset $B \subseteq X$ and an element $a \in A$, either $a \in B$ or $a \not \in B$.

How might you match up functions $A \to 2$ with subsets of $A$?

**Bigger hint:** *(hover mouse over grey box to see)*

> Every subset has a characteristic function, and every function $A \to 2$ is the characteristic function of a subset.

Answer (score 2):

Given an $f:A\mapsto\{0,1\}$, map $f$ to $\{a\in A:f(a)=1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{0, 1\}$ be the described two element set.
You can build $\phi : 2^A \to P(A)$ which maps each function $f \in 2^A$ to the set $A \in P(A)$ which consists of elements $x$ that for them $f(x) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Try $F\colon 2^A\to P(A)$, $f\mapsto f^{-1}(1)$.